# configuring applet options in the <applet> tag

Tags: java, applet

I must not be very good at googling today. I want to set the option that appears in the applet config that disable applets for being able to access the certificate store of the browser, but not for all the applets, just for one applet.

Do you know where can I find all the applets options?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

W3C reference for Objects, Images, and Applets: http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/objects.html

Sun reference for the Applet tag: http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/deployment/deployment-guide/applet.html

A lot of resources about the topic of signed applets: http://mindprod.com/jgloss/signedapplets.html

Comment: but, do you know any options for avoiding looking for the browsers certificates?

Comment: Are you using some security framework? Not sure about what do you want to accomplish... Applets are almost obsolete, you should move to JNLP.